# How to view records in one excel sheet to another in excel, keeping one sheet as a template for all?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a excel file and in sheet1 value looks like this

[image]

The first column in sheet1 is hyperlink to sheet2, by clicking it should look like this

[image]

Output needed is by clicking first column in sheet1, respective row data should be viewed in sheet2. How can we do this using macro or vba or by any means. Please help and thank you.

Currently I can do it referencing the cells in sheet2 like this

```
='sheet1'!A3
='sheet1'!B3
='sheet1'!C3
```

and my hyperlink is like this -

```
book1.xls-sheet2!A1
```

For this I have to make new sheets for each records in the sheet1. I want all records (rows) in sheet1 should be viewed with sheet2 as a template.

Comment: Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question. [No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/).

Comment: Sorry, I edited . I am looking for just help on how to do this @Pᴇʜ

Comment: Check out [In Excel, can I use a hyperlink to run vba macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728600/in-excel-can-i-use-a-hyperlink-to-run-vba-macro). You will need to write a macro to write the data into the other sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is what I get from tremendous search

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Target.Resize(, 4).Copy
    Sheets("Template").Range("C3").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```